# Conditionally change the 'targets' attribute of a struts2 form based on action result

Tags: java, jquery, struts2

I wanted to know if its possible to conditionally set the 'targets' attribute of a form submission based on the result the action outputs?

Edit: I think i'm being misunderstood. If i have a form:

```
<s:form action= "someFixedStruts2Action" >
    <!-- form fields -->
<sj:submit targets="ConditionalTarget">
```

How do I make ConditionalTarget change depending on what someFixedAction outputs?

Bump!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is not necessary, you can do this:

```
<s:form action="%{#myAction}">
    ...
</s:form>
```

and set the action, when you renders the form.

Answer (score 0):

with jquery, you can, at any time, as follows: `jQuery('form').attr('action','you_coice.html');`

I hope help you